# Short URL for Mediawiki installation in web root

Tags: php, .htaccess, mediawiki, short-url

I have a Mediawiki installation running on my web root. E.g. the main page can be accessed via

```
http://example.com/index.php?title=Main_Page
```

I would like to change it so that the short URL is

```
http://example.com/Main_Page
```

My configuration is as follows

```
#.htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

.

```
// LocalSettings.php
$wgScriptPath = "..";
$wgArticlePath = "/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;
```

But I get a 500 error with this configuration.

This is a server where there is a `~/user_root/` folder. This folder contains the public HTML files for the root domain of the user, e.g. `user-root.com`.

The folder contains several subfolders, e.g. in this case `~/user_root/example`, which is accessible via the mentioned URL above, `example.com`.

Is the problem based on this folder/subfolder hierarchy and the `$wgScriptPath` setting? Should

```
$wgScriptPath = "..";
```

be replaced by something else than this relative path? Please advise, if you need more information.

Comment: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache

Comment: That's where I'm coming from, but couldn't get to run it on the root dir (respectively the subdir which is the root of my domain).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your `$wgScriptPath` is wrong. Use:

```
$wgScriptPath = "/";
```

Your rewrite rules also seem unlikely to be what you desire, especially that `^.*$ /index.php` (although it might be harmless, coming last).

> If you are using a root url instead of a normal short url you will need to use the following
>   instead (to ensure that existing files and directories are not seen as article, e.g. "`/index.php`" "`/images`" etc.):
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
> ```

([Source](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache#Setting_up_the_rewrite_rules))